# No me funciona boton de descarga pdf en ANDROID

Tags: android, pdf, botón, jspdf, android-button

He creado un boton que me descargue un pdf con datos adquiridos de un formulario. En la parte web funciona correctamente, luego en IOS tambien funciona bien pero en Android  no. Alguien tuvo algun problema similar? Desde ya muchas gracias.
Adjunto Codigo:

```
HTML:<div id="pdf">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" style="width: 100%"
        name="botonDescarga" onclick="test()">
        <i class="fas fa-download"></i> Descarga
        </button>
```

```
JS: function test() { var doc = new jsPDF({
    compress : false,
    orientation : 'p',
    unit : 'px',
    format : 'a4'
});doc.save('Cotización.pdf');}
```

Comment: ¿que hace en android?

Comment: En Android no hace nada, apreto el boton y no responde.

Answer (score 0):

En un dispositivo android no creo que pueda ser posible salvar el archivo directamente con la función

```
JS: function test() { var doc = new jsPDF({
    compress : false,
    orientation : 'p',
    unit : 'px',
    format : 'a4'
});doc.save('Cotización.pdf');}
```

Debes definir una ruta en el dispositivo para salvar el archivo.

```
 const dirDownloads = File.externalRootDirectory + 'Downloads/';
```

Buscando sobre este problema encontré una [respuesta de Ankit Kumawat](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69300449/250260) donde realizó una función para guardar el archivo en un diretorio de las apps móvil,

```
const pdfDownload = async () => {
var doc = new jsPDF();
doc.setFontSize(40);
doc.text("Example jsPDF", 35, 25)
let pdfOutput = doc.output();
    if (isPlatform("android")) {
      // for Android device
      const directory = File.externalRootDirectory + 'Download/';
      const fileName = `invoice-${new Date().getTime()}.pdf`
      File.writeFile(directory, fileName, pdfOutput, true).then(succ => {
        FileOpener.showOpenWithDialog(directory + fileName, 'application/pdf')
          .then(() => console.log('File opened'))
          .catch(error => console.log('Error opening file', error));
      },
        err => {
          console.log(" writing File error : ", err)
        })
    } else if (isPlatform("ios")) {
      // for iOS device
      console.log('ios device')
      const directory = File.tempDirectory;
      const fileName = `invoice-${new Date().getTime()}.pdf`
      File.writeFile(directory, fileName, pdfOutput, true).then(success => {
        FileOpener.showOpenWithDialog(directory + fileName, 'application/pdf')
          .then(() => console.log('File opened'))
          .catch(e => console.log('Error opening file', e));
      },
        err => {
          console.log(" writing File error : ", err)
        })
    } else {
      // for desktop
      doc.save("invoice.pdf");
    }

}
```

Comment: Buenas tardes Jorgesys. Estos dias estuve probando lo que me pasaste pero me sigue sin funcionar, tambien he probado mediante el metodo window pero tampoco hay caso. Yo estoy usando jsPDF..

Comment: Es importante comentar que mensaje se muestra, tanto en este código como en el LogCat se debe registrar algún mensaje para determinar el problema.